# Cpp Operator = between 2 classes

Tags: c++, operators

I have a surprising issue in VS2010.

This is the header.h of my main.cpp

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
public:
    double x,y;
    A();
    ~A();
    A(const A &obj);
    A(const B &obj);
    A& operator=(const A &obj);
};

class B
{
public:
    double x,y;
    B();
    ~B();
    B(const B &obj);
    B& operator=(const B &obj);
};
```

The main.cpp is containing the declaration of methods and :

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    A t;
    B u;
    A a(u);
    t=u;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, to do

```
A a(u);
```

I had to add this method

```
A(const B &obj);
```

But for

```
t=u;
```

It uses

```
A& operator=(const A &obj);
```

Why I don't get an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid this, you should mark your "A from B" constructor as `explicit`:

```
explicit A(const B &obj);
```

Any constructor not marked as explicit will be used by the compiler for implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

by adding `A(const B &obj);` you provided a way to convert B to A, which is used in `t=u;` so the compiler can do what you ask and no error is needed.  The conversion can be done because the parameter `const A &obj` allows conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If, for whatever reason, the `A(const B &obj)` is meaninful but you also want `t=u` to fail then you have to disable implicit type conversion using the [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1y7x448.aspx) keyword.

This means that only when you specifically cast B as an instance of A will the conversion be performed.